# Get Renderer of another game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 3d cube with a unlit\transparent texture. I'm trying to get access to the material offset parameter.

```
public class scroll : MonoBehaviour {

    public float speed = 0.5f;
    public GameObject stars, bg;
    public Component ren;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        ren = GameObject.Find("stars").GetComponent<Renderer>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Vector2 offset = new Vector2(0, Time.time * speed);

        //here I want to change offset of the texture (shader: unlit\transparent)

    }
}
```

I tried

```
ren.renderer.material.mainTextureOffeset = offset;
```

got an Error:

> `UnityEngine.Material` does not contain a definition for
>   `mainTextureOffeset` and no extension method `mainTextureOffeset` of
>   type `UnityEngine.Material` could be found. Are you missing an
>   assembly reference?

structure:

-WORLD (this script attached here)

--stars (3D cube)

Comment: So have you solved it?

Answer (score 3):

You have got a typo in your code: `mainTextureOffeset` instead of `mainTextureOffset`. I don't see any other possibilities for `UnityEngine.Material` not to contain  `mainTextureOffset`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use ren.material.mainTextureOffset, since ren is a reference to the renderer of "stars" and not  a reference to the GameObject "stars".

EDIT: As @Bagdan Gilevich stated in his answer you should also change mainTextureOffeset to mainTextureOffset.

Comment: Oh think i got it. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewBro you said that you tried "ren.renderer.material.mainTextureOffeset = offset;" you should try "ren.material.mainTextureOffeset = offset;" since ren is the reference to the renderer